# Writing values back to a form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form called Main. On it I have

- a text box to hold the record ID
- a combobox to select from existing records or enter a name for the new record
- a text box to hold the name from the combobox
- a button to open a form that lets us enter additional data and create a new record
- a button to open a form that lets us edit an existing record

I cascade the row source for the list in the combobox. If the entry is not in the list,
the NotInList event

- Copies the name in the combobox is moved to a text box on Main
- Loads the create form's and copies the name from Main to the appropriate field on the create form.

All that works fine. The problem is that when I hit Save on the create form, I cannot write values back to the Main form correctly. I want to write the name that came from the combobox back to the combobox on Main, and write the record ID to the text field on Main.

It's two lines of code. If I change their order, the output changes. Either the combobox ends up blank, or the record ID text field ends up blank.

While I was debugging this I can see the values exist, but I could not make the assignments. The last time I tried combobox.text it complained about the value not being
in the list, so I ran the query for the row source, but the record did not show up in the combobox list, but is in the table. See the two lines of code (bold) below.

```
    Private Sub cmbSaveClose_Click()
    Dim x As Integer

    x = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save changes?", 4, "Exit?")

    'VbNo constant throws back #7
    'VbYes constant throws back #6

     Me.Txt32 = DLookup("InsuranceCarrierContractID", "ICCDupRecordCheckQ")

     If x = 7 Then
     Exit Sub
     End If

     If IsNull(Me.Txt32) Then

        Me.Txt31 = Form_frmMain.Txt65

        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

**Forms!frmMain.cboInsuranceCarrierContract = Me.InsuranceCarrierContractID
Forms!frmMain.Txt66 = Me.InsuranceCarrierContractID**

        DoCmd.Close

        Forms!frmMain!InsuranceCarrierContract.RowSource = 
                              " SELECT InsuranceCarrierContract.ContractNumber " & _
                              " FROM InsuranceCarrierContract " & _
                              " ORDER BY InsuranceCarrierContract.ContractNumber;"

'Other stuff,works fine. 

    Form_frmMain.cboInsuranceCarrierContract.Locked = False
    Form_frmMain.cboInsuranceCarrierContract.BackColor = 
                                 Form_frmMain.cboInsuranceCarrier.BackColor
    
Else
    Me.Undo
    DoCmd.Close

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried to ReQuery and ReFresh the form after you change the data?

Comment: ReQuery never works for me anywhere. The point of the Select is to reQuery the list. Overkill maybe.  I'll try both. Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWaage Moving the code around and doing a requery worked. Thanks. It's been all day, and I discovered that I can requery instead of updating the row source. Much less work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for David, so adding it as an Answer:

ReQuery and ReFresh the form after you change the data.

```
Me.Requery 
Me.Refresh
```

from within the form module, or externally:

```
Forms("MyFormName").Requery
Forms("MyFormName").Refresh
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191903.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836021.aspx